# Batch command for geting date in specified format

Tags: date, batch-file

Is it possible to specify date format (maybe as paramater or some similar way) which batch command ***date*** returns or it only depends on windows regional settings? 
What I would like is to somehow specify date format when i call ***date*** so that the batch script can extract day, month and year and save them in variables. The problem is that some machines return dd/MM/yyyy and some MM/dd/yyyy so in one case day and month would be switched. Some also use dots as separators. 
Can I somehow tell ***date*** to return for example MM/dd/yyyy so I can differentiate which is day and which is month?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if these will definitely resolve your issue, but please take a look at Date and Time functions on link http://commandline.co.uk/lib/treeview/index.php.

Answer (score 1):

```
c:\> WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
```

Creates the following environment variables:

Day, DayOfWeek, Hour, Milliseconds, Minute, Month, Quarter, Second, WeekInMonth, Year

Which can be accessed as usual: `%Year%`

To see the values use `wmic path win32_localtime`

**note:** The values can be blank. On my desktop, Milliseconds has no value.

**note 2:** If you use this in the command line, replace `%%` with `%`

Inspiration for this answer [Setting a windows batch file variable to the day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364147/setting-a-windows-batch-file-variable-to-the-day-of-the-week#comment15181644_11367625)