# run a batch script only on weekdays/selected days

Tags: batch-file, date-format

I have a batch file to take DB backup, scheduled to run at a selected time everyday. But I don't want to run the same on weekends or say on selected days. On my server, `%DATE%` returns 07/08/2013. So doing `%DATE:~0,3%` returns `07/` instead of day.

Is there a way to return day and then using an if-else, I can guide the program to flow as per the requirement.

My server runs Windows server 2003.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a windows batch file variable to the day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364147/setting-a-windows-batch-file-variable-to-the-day-of-the-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for `weekend`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate^|find "REG_SZ"') do set "ssShortDate=%%b"
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /f /v sShortDate /d "d" >nul
FOR /f %%a IN ("%date%") DO SET "dow=%%a"
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /f /v sShortDate /d "%ssShortDate%" >NUL
IF /i "%dow:~0,1%"=="s" ECHO weekend!
```

Comment: Dangerous... But effective! Language dependent.

Comment: @LS_dev Yes, it depends on local settings and (only?) works for English and German. But there are other solutions at SO and the Web without access to the registry :)

Comment: @LS_dev: Both the scripts (yours and Endoro's) run for me... Many thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning about WMI, and following should run fine:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,* DELIMS==" %%v IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get /FORMAT:VALUE') DO IF "%%v" == "DayOfWeek" SET DayOfWeek=%%w
IF %DayOfWeek% == 0 REM Do whatever you want for Sunday
...
IF %DayOfWeek% == 6 REM Do whatever you want for Saturday
```

EDIT: Changed, according comment on [Win32_LocalTime class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) stating documentation is wrong.

Comment: saturday = 6, while Sunday = 7 on my system....Is it anything to do with local dependency or are these codes universal in nature!!

Comment: Hum, my machine also tells me that today, Wed, is 3... However, MSDN states that "Current day of the current week that matches the query (1–7). By convention, the value 1 (one) is always Sunday, regardless of the culture or the locale set on the machine." in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393244(v=vs.85).aspx ...