# Input date parameter and return day of week in batch file

Tags: date, batch-file, dayofweek

I need to send a date to a batch file and have it return the day of the week. The date parameter could be in the past or in the future. I have looked through a number of date functions but they are all using today's date. Is it possible to return the day of the week by sending a date parameter to a batch file? I am using Windows 7.

Comment: are you really constrained to pure batch? What you ask is very easy in powershell (you may call it from cmd/batch): `powershell date('2014-05-18') -Uformat %V`

Comment: sorry it should be `%u` I misread you want week not day. This returns number, there are other options available as well

Comment: Actually, I need the day of the week. For example: Mon, Tue. Unfortunately, I do need it to remain in batch format.

Comment: that would be `%a`(or use .net format as Stephan shows), for invocation from batch see his answer too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a windows batch file variable to the day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364147/setting-a-windows-batch-file-variable-to-the-day-of-the-week)

Answer (score 2):

with the help of Powershell:

```
set a=03.12.2013
for /f %%i in ('powershell ^(Get-Date %a% -f dddd^)') do set long=%%i
for /f %%i in ('powershell ^(Get-Date %a% -f ddd^)') do set short=%%i
echo Day is %long% (%short%)
```

Answer (score 1):

save this as `.bat` and change the `date1` to the date you want

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end/*** Javascript comment
@echo off
set "date1=04/14/2014"
(
    mshta "about:<title>dow</title><body onload='init("%date1%")'><script language='javascript' src='file://%~dpnxf0'></script><span id='arg1'>%date1%</span></body>" 
) | (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%B in ('more') do (
        echo day of the week: %%B
    )
)
exit /b 0

**/

function init(ds) {
    //var dt = document.getElementById('arg1').value;
    var the_date=new Date(Date.parse(ds));
    var the_day=the_date.getDay();
    //alert(the_day);
    var fso= new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1);
    //fso.Write(the_date.getDay());
    close(fso.Write(the_day));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a batch script using VBS to get the weekday.

```
:: Get weekday and day of week number, for a date
@echo off  
if "%~1"=="" echo Use this to get the day of week: "%~nx0" dd-mm-yyyy& pause & goto :EOF
set file="%temp%\%~n0.temp.vbs"
echo>%file% WScript.Echo weekday(#%~1#)
for /f %%a in ('cscript //nologo %file%') do set "daynum=%%a"
del %file%
for /f "tokens=%daynum% delims=," %%a in ("Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday") do set "weekday=%%a"
echo dow is "%daynum%" - "%weekday%"
pause
```