# Using %date% in batch script

Tags: date, batch-file

I want to have some code like this:

```
if %date% equ "Mon" echo do this do that
```

but the cmd window closes after encountering this code, even if I put

```
pause
```

after it.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Just echo the `date` variable at the command prompt.  Do you think that comparison will ever be equal regardless of you forgetting to put quotes around the variable.  The proper way to debug a batch file is to run the batch file from the cmd prompt. Do not run it with your mouse.

Comment: But what if I want to say: if %date% equ "Mon" echo goto school

Comment: You are doing a string comparison.  If you have quotes on one side of the comparison you must have quotes on the other side of the comparison.  The date variable is region dependent.  Your date variable will not display the same as mine depending on which countries we each live in.

Comment: You probably want to use `IF /I "%DATE:~,3%"=="Mon"` or possibly `IF NOT "%DATE:Mon=%"=="%DATE%"`, however neither are safe or robust methods in anything other than your specific current user environment.

Comment: My %date% doesn't even have any day of week

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a windows batch file variable to the day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364147/setting-a-windows-batch-file-variable-to-the-day-of-the-week)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use:

```bat
IF /I "%DATE:~,3%"=="Mon" (Echo Do this
    Echo Do that)
```

Or possibly:

```bat
IF NOT "%DATE:Mon=%"=="%DATE%" (Echo Do this
    Echo Do that)
```

However neither of those are safe or robust methods in anything other than your specific current user environment.

This is how I'd get the day of the week into a variable using a batch file with `WMIC`:

```bat
For /F %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek') Do For %%B In (
    Monday.1 Tuesday.2 Wednesday.3 Thursday.4 Friday.5 Saturday.6 Sunday.0
) Do If "%%~xB"==".%%A" Set "WDName=%%~nB"
```

*Line `2` can be optionally adjusted to start with `Sunday.0 Monday.1` etc. if necessary or `Lunes.1 Martes.2` etc. depending upon your language.*

You could then use:

```bat
If "%WDName%"=="Monday" (Echo Do this
    Echo Do that)
```

*Although `(Get-Date).DayOfWeek` in PowerShell seems so much simpler.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete `cmd` file that will give you what you need. The important bit is all in the `getDow` function and, hopefully, it's commented well enough to understand. First, the test harness:

```
@echo off
rem Test harness bit - just get current date and compare with getDow.

date /t
call :getDow num long short
echo Day of week is %num%, %long%, %short%
goto :eof
```

The function itself is:

```
rem Usage: call :getDow <num> <long> <short>
rem        <num> will receive the numeric form (0-6).
rem        <long> will receive the long form (e.g., Monday).
rem        <short> will receive the short form (e.g., Mon).

:getDow
    rem Create local scope to prevent information leakage.

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Create array for translation.

    set idx=0
    for %%a in (Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday) do (
        set dow[!idx!]=%%a
        set /a "idx += 1"
    )

    rem Get the numeric day of week, mmi command will
    rem output 'DayOfWeek=N' and we just extract N.

    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek /value ^| findstr "DayOfWeek="') do (
        set localNum=%%a
    )
    set localStr=!dow[%localNum%]!

    rem Properly end scope but let selected information leak.

    endlocal&&set %1=%localNum%&&set %2=%localStr%&&set %3=%localStr:~0,3%
    goto :eof
```

A sample run of that script gives:

```
Tue Jun 05
Day of week is 2, Tuesday, Tue
```

Comment: That uses the same method as my already posted answer, only it requires delayed expansion, and uses a whole lot more lines. _(mine's a single line split into 3 for readability and easier modification by the end user!)_

Comment: @Compo, I'm sure if yours is better, it will garner more votes, I'm equally sure I could point out faults in *your* answer were I so inclined :-) Myself, I prefer to have general purpose functions for all this sort of stuff so it's easy to code up.

Comment: I have not picked out any faults in your answer, have I? _(mentioning that it uses a whole lot more lines does not constitute a fault nor was it implied)_. But, I'd be happy were you to explain to me the faults in my code, in order that I learn from them moving forward, thank you.

Comment: @Compo, apologies if I misread, "too long" certainly seems like a criticism :-) On your own answer, I think you may need to change the values checked, I'm pretty certain the DOW values from WMI are 0 thru 6 rather than 1 thru 7. Other than that, it's fine.

Comment: Thank you for that, even though I've used the code over a good few years, I've obviously never had a need to use it on my weekend and was unaware of the error in it. I have therefore adjusted my answer accordingly.