# How to set date from cmd after retrieving it

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following code

```
set x=%date /T %
date 16/12/2012
date 15/12/2012

some stuff goes here    
echo set your date

date %x%       <--- getting error in that line.
pause
```

So how can i get the date in the format dd/mm/yy

Comment: use Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"  or get-date -format g

Comment: @RachelGallen `Get-Date` is available in PowerShell, not in `cmd`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the date format of dd/mm/yy by using `wmic` command. This command allows you to get current date without getting affected by regional settings.

```
    @echo off
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do (
        IF NOT "%%~f"=="" (
            set /a FormattedDate=10000 * %%f + 100 * %%d + %%a
            set FormattedDate=!FormattedDate:~-2,2!/!FormattedDate:~-4,2!/!FormattedDate:~-6,2!
        )
    )

    echo %FormattedDate%
    PAUSE
```

You can save it as `date.bat` and run this batch file by executing the following in command prompt:

```
C:\>date.bat
21/01/13
Press any key to continue...
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Two more ways that do not depend on the time settings (both taken from [:How get data/time independent from localization:](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4555)).And both also get the day of the week and none of them requires admin permissions!:

1.**MAKECAB** - will work on EVERY windows system (fast but creates a small temp file ) (the foxidrive script):

```
@echo off
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
   set "current-date=%%e-%%b-%%c"
   set "current-time=%%d"
   set "weekday=%%a"
)
del ~.*
popd
echo %weekday% %current-date% %current-time%
pause
```

2. **ROBOCOPY** - it's not native command for windows xp and win 2003 but can be [downloaded from microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657)  .But is built-in in everything from Vista and above:

```
 @echo off
setlocal 
for /f "skip=8 tokens=2,3,4,5,6,7,8 delims=: " %%D in ('robocopy /l * \ \ /ns /nc /ndl /nfl /np /njh /XF * /XD *') do (
 set "dow=%%D"
 set "month=%%E"
 set "day=%%F"
 set "HH=%%G"
 set "MM=%%H"
 set "SS=%%I"
 set "year=%%J"
)

echo Day of the week: %dow%
echo Day of the month : %day%
echo Month : %month%
echo hour : %HH%
echo minutes : %MM%
echo seconds : %SS%
echo year : %year%
endlocal
```

And three more ways that uses other windows script languages.They will give you more flexibility e.g. you can get week of the year, time in milliseconds and so on.

3.**JSCRIPT/BATCH** hybrid (need to be saved as `.bat`).Jscript is available on every system form NT and above , as a part of windows script host ([though can be disabled through the registry it's a rare case](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198684.aspx)):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* ---Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

@echo off
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0"
exit /b 0
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function GetCurrentDate() {
        // Today date time which will used to set as default date.
        var todayDate = new Date();
        todayDate = todayDate.getFullYear() + "-" +
                       ("0" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
                       ("0" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + ("0" + todayDate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +
                       ("0" + todayDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

        return todayDate;
    }

WScript.Echo(GetCurrentDate());
```

4.**VSCRIPT/BATCH** hybrid ([Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)) same case as jscript , but hybridization is not so perfect:

```
:sub echo(str) :end sub
echo off
'>nul 2>&1|| copy /Y %windir%\System32\doskey.exe %windir%\System32\'.exe >nul
'& echo current date:
'& cscript /nologo /E:vbscript "%~f0"
'& exit /b

'0 = vbGeneralDate - Default. Returns date: mm/dd/yy and time if specified: hh:mm:ss PM/AM.
'1 = vbLongDate - Returns date: weekday, monthname, year
'2 = vbShortDate - Returns date: mm/dd/yy
'3 = vbLongTime - Returns time: hh:mm:ss PM/AM
'4 = vbShortTime - Return time: hh:mm

WScript.echo  Replace(FormatDateTime(Date,1),", ","-")
```

5.**POWERSHELL** - can be installed on every machine that has .net - download from Microsoft ([v1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7217) , [v2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929/bg) , [v3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) (only for win7 and above)).Installed by default on everything form Win7/Win2008 and above :

```
C:\>powershell get-date -format "{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm}"
```

6.**Self-compiled jscript.net/batch** (never seen a windows machine without .net so I think this is a pretty portable):

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /****** silent line that start jscript comment ******

@echo off
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       compile the script    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal
if exist "%~n0.exe" goto :skip_compilation

set "frm=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"
:: searching the latest installed .net framework
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('dir /b /s /a:d /o:-n "%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v*"') do (
    if exist "%%v\jsc.exe" (
        rem :: the javascript.net compiler
        set "jsc=%%~dpsnfxv\jsc.exe"
        goto :break_loop
    )
)
echo jsc.exe not found && exit /b 0
:break_loop


call %jsc% /nologo /out:"%~n0.exe" "%~dpsfnx0"
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::       end of compilation    ::::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:skip_compilation

"%~n0.exe" 

exit /b 0


****** end of jscript comment ******/
import System;
import System.IO;

var dt=DateTime.Now;
 Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"));
```

7.**Logman** This cannot get the year and day of the week.It's comparatively slow , also creates a temp file and is based on the time stamps that logman puts on its log files.Will work everything from XP and above.Probably will be never used by anybody - including me - but is one more way...

```
@echo off
setlocal
del /q /f %temp%\timestampfile_*

Logman.exe stop ts-CPU 1>nul 2>&1
Logman.exe delete ts-CPU 1>nul 2>&1

Logman.exe create counter ts-CPU  -sc 2 -v mmddhhmm -max 250 -c "\Processor(_Total)\%% Processor Time" -o %temp%\timestampfile_ >nul
Logman.exe start ts-CPU 1>nul 2>&1

Logman.exe stop ts-CPU >nul 2>&1
Logman.exe delete ts-CPU >nul 2>&1
for /f "tokens=2 delims=_." %%t in  ('dir /b %temp%\timestampfile_*^&del /q/f %temp%\timestampfile_*') do set timestamp=%%t

echo %timestamp%
echo MM: %timestamp:~0,2%
echo dd: %timestamp:~2,2%
echo hh: %timestamp:~4,2%
echo mm: %timestamp:~6,2%

endlocal
exit /b 0
```

[more information about get-date function](http://ss64.com/ps/get-date.html).

Comment: robocopy method should have milliseconds when copying files, correct?  if so, shouldn't we be able to copy the milliseconds also?

Answer (score 1):

This is tested on my system and it sets the date to required format. In case of error message of not "not enough required privileges  or A required privilege is not held by the client" try running the script as Administrator. This should work fine then.

```
@echo off
set x=%DATE:~0,2%/%DATE:~3,2%/%DATE:~6,4%
echo %x%
set date=%x%
echo %date%
```

Comment: Not working!
the date format dd/mm/-yy is not accepted.
try removing set from set date,you get the error.

Comment: This worked for me:
`set x=%DATE:~4,2%/%DATE:~7,2%/%DATE:~10,4%`  if the format is "Thu 03/03/2016"

Answer (score 1):

have you tried SET x=%date:~-10%, i know it works with windows 7.

Comment: This helped me because some systems return the day of week while others didn't. This removed the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment `set x=%date /T %` is wrong. The percent signs expand variables, they don't provide command substitution functionality.

Windows already provides an automatic environment variable `%DATE%` with the current date (also a variable `%TIME%` with the current time), so you can simply do this:

```
set x=%DATE%
date 16/12/2012
date 15/12/2012

rem stuff

date %x%
pause
```

Comment: try running the code!
date 21-jan-13
The system cannot accept the date entered.

Comment: Fix your date format. `date` can only process numeric values.

Comment: this line "set x=%DATE%" gives x= 21-jan-13

Comment: That is because you defined that particular (short) date format in your computer's regional settings. Change that from `DD-MMM-YYYY` to `DD/MM/YYYY` (or `DD-MM-YYYY`) and the problem will vanish.

Comment: Most systems I know use a numeric short date format. Anyway, you already got a solution that takes care of this issue. If you're not satisfied with it I'd recommend switching to a different script language. Batch is a rather bad choice when it comes to dealing with date or time values.

Comment: agree with you! it is really nonsense to write that much code for just getting the date. i like bash scripts. but this time i don't have any choice.

Answer (score 0):

Dale's answer helped me a lot. I modified his solution to get the time in format **hhmmdd**:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Fill variables: %%a=Day %%b=Hour %%c=Minute %%d=Month %%e=Second %%f=Year
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-6 delims= " %%a in ('wmic path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') do (
    IF NOT "%%~f"=="" (
    rem Adding leading zeros:
        set /a FormattedTime=1000000 + 10000 * %%b + 100 * %%c + %%e
    rem reading from the right to left: 
        set FormattedTime=!FormattedTime:~-6,2!!FormattedTime:~-4,2!!FormattedTime:~-2,2!
    )
)
echo %FormattedTime%
```

Comment: for `hhmmss` (I think, `hhmmdd`is a typo) there is a much easyer way: `for /f %%i in ('wmic os get localdatetime^|find "."') do set x=%%i` and `echo %x:~8,6%` (including leading zeros)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I've found a way to do it without wmic:

At first, I've found a kind of answer and work with that:

> You can try this ! This should work on windows machines.
>
> for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%I IN (`echo %date%`) do echo "%%I" "%%J" "%%K"
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/14820126/3735825

Then I worked with this and did this one:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/, " %%I IN (`echo %date%`) do ECHO %%L-%%K-%%J
```

It deletes the spaces and the separators from the %date% command and let you use any kind of part of the date as a variable; for example if I want to set the date as YYYYMMDD The code should be like this:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/, " %%I IN (`echo %date%`) do ECHO %%L%%K%%J
```

If do you need the variables alone and you need to use them as you want, then you can play with the following variables:

```
%%I = Day of Week
%%J = Day
%%K = Month
%%L = Year
```

I hope it help anyone.

Comment: 1. Problem was SETTING date, not GETTING it. 2. `wmic` has a big advantage: it is independent to local settings. For example `echo %date%` gives me `11.02.2015`

Comment: Stephan, sorry I was having a problem getting it, but this is what i do for setting it:

Comment: Stephan, sorry I was having a problem getting it, but this is what i do for GET:  `for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/, " %%I IN ('echo %date%') do SET yyyy=%%L || SET mm=%%K || SET dd=%%J` and for setting the date is: `date 09-15-11  (Like date mm-dd-yy)`

Comment: Another problem with date is that it respects the format that has been set up by the user, so different machines give different formats (30-Aug-17, for example).  Your post was still useful.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
set DATE_NOW=!date:~6,4!!date:~0,2!!date:~3,2!   
set TIME_NOW=!time:~0,2!!time:~3,2!!time:~6,2!   

echo %DATE_NOW%                                  
echo %TIME_NOW%
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need a date in format YYYY-MM-DD, not in 2019-May-09. So I modify universal decision from **npocmaka** with make cab:

```
@echo off
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
    set "current-year=%%e"
    set "current-month=%%b"
    set "current-day=%%c"
    set "current-time=%%d"
    set "weekday=%%a"
)
del ~.*
popd

CALL :CASE_%current-month% 
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :DEFAULT_CASE 

ECHO Done.
GOTO NEXT

:CASE_Jan
    set "current-month=01"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Feb
    set "current-month=02"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Mar
    set "current-month=03"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Apr
    set "current-month=04"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_May
    set "current-month=05"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Jun
    set "current-month=06"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Jul
    set "current-month=07"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Aug
    set "current-month=08"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Sep
    set "current-month=09"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Oct
    set "current-month=10"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Nov
    set "current-month=11"
    GOTO END_CASE
:CASE_Dec
    set "current-month=12"
    GOTO END_CASE


:DEFAULT_CASE
  set "current-month=xx"
  echo "Month is not in the English language! Fix it!"  
  GOTO END_CASE
:END_CASE
  VER > NUL # reset ERRORLEVEL
  GOTO :EOF # return from CALL

:NEXT
echo %weekday% %current-year%-%current-month%-%current-day% %current-time%
pause
```

Tested on Windows XP SP3 and Server 2008 R2 SP1.