# Get Date in YYYYMMDD format in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to get the date in YYYYMMDD format in batch file.

I am doing this using :

```
set mydate=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%
echo %mydate%
```

I need it to be consistent across system, even on changing the time settings.

Please advise.

Comment: You may refer to [this][1] link for more information.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427490/how-to-set-date-from-cmd-after-retrieving-it/14435810#14435810

Comment: echo %date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%

Comment: @AliBayat that doesn't work "consistent across systems" as the OP requires

Answer (score 66):

If, after reading the other questions and viewing the links mentioned in the comment sections, you still can't figure it out, read on.

First of all, where you're going wrong is the offset.

It should look more like this...

```
set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~6,2%/%date:~4,2%
echo %mydate%
```

If the date was `Tue 12/02/2013` then it would display it as `2013/02/12`.

To remove the slashes, the code would look more like

```
set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%
echo %mydate%
```

which would output `20130212`

And a hint for doing it in the future, if `mydate` equals something like `%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%` or the like, you probably forgot a tilde (~).

Comment: The offsets are not necessarily wrong: it all depends on your current regional settings for date/time.
On my PC, %date% gives Sun 04/26/2014.
There's no safe way that I can think of that would it safely this way

Comment: Exclamation mark ! doesn't seem to work in DOS ??

Comment: Where the exclamation mark fails in DOS, replace it with a percent sign %. That worked for me anyhoo.

Comment: This is a great approach. To get `yyyyMMdd` (e.g., 20161224), use `set CURRENT_DATE=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%`.

Comment: (1) exclamation mark does not work (2) doesn't work on other locales

Comment: This requires 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion'

Comment: @Yves. +1 for pointing that out. The rest of you guys: next time, use an example with a day greater than 12 (so it's clear that iy isn't the month). In the US, we use the inexplicable mm/dd/yyyy format -- neither least significant nor most significant part first. Breaking it down to make this clearer: set  startYear=%date:~10,4%; set startmonth=%date:~4,2%; set   startDay=%date:~7,2%, set startDate=%startYear%-%startMonth%-%startDay%; echo %startDate% gives 2018-03-25, which can be used as part of a filename which conveniently sorts alphabetically in date order.

Comment: I don't see the point of using ! instead of %, unless the statement is inside a long running for loop, where the date might change during execution. OTOH, I prefer delayed expansion, too -- it prevents unexpected things from happening in the disaster of a scripting language that for whatever reason, we still use.

Comment: @vallismortis this is a very defective approach. The OP has specifically said "I need it to be consistent across system, even on changing the time settings."

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I've been using this approach for nightly backup/restore scripts for over a year on multiple systems in different time zones, and it has never failed for me. That said, I would be interested in an alternative answer that solves the issues you refer to.

Comment: @vallismortis it's absolutely not related to timezone but about [time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_representation_by_country)

Comment: As @phuclv said, this only works if you have configured your system to a specific date format (the default US format, I think). It doesn't work if %DATE% returns the format "20/11/2020" instead of "Fri 11/20/2020", which seems to be standard on UK systems, and I'm guessing most countries. I know this because I just worked out that's why a client's batch jobs aren't working on a new server. ;)

Comment: Apparently today is `2021/0/02`? -1

Comment: For anyone looking for quick hack and tldr: `echo %date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%-%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%`

Comment: All of this depends on the current Windows date format settings and won't work in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this ! This should work on windows machines.

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%I IN (`echo %date%`) do echo "%%I" "%%J" "%%K"
```

Comment: Not, when separator is '/'. For region independent approaches see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us

Comment: Error: "%%I was unexpected at this time."

Comment: %% vs % one for batch file the other for command line

Comment: Rather that: for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A IN (`echo %date%`) do echo "MON=%%B" "DAY=%%C" "YEAR=%%D"

Comment: @ShaiAlon the double percent "%%" is for running inside a batch file. For just trying from DOS - oops - CMD prompt, use single percent "%"