# Looking for a simple command line program to check whether a particular folder exists, if yes, make another folder in that folder

Tags: cmd

Is there a simple command line program to check whether a particular folder exists, and if yes, make another folder in that folder?

Comment: Please post the question what you have tried and where the error is occuring.

Comment: This is more of a requirement than a question. Voting to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if exist C:\Temp\ mkdir C:\Temp\1

---

m0Re "advanced" way:

```
@echo off

set root=C:\temp
set new=\NewFolder

if exist %root% goto L2

goto L3

:L2
if not exist %root%%new% mkdir %root%%new%

:L3
```

Comment: thanks Zam..bt i'm still struggling to get results

Comment: permission issue? do you get any error? can you show any of your code?

Comment: I tried to modify your code a bit. actually I want to create folder by the name of year. Then check if folder exists in this folder by the name of month, if not create it. Then create a folder of today's date and then copy backup files in it. For Example \2014\Feb\18.



@echo off
set year=%year%
set month = %month%
set dd=%date%


if exist %year%\%month% goto L2

goto L3

:L2
if not exist %year%\%month% mkdir %root%%new%%dd%

:L3

Comment: just suggestion: try to use more simple way

"mkdir %date%"

Comment: i am also using batch files for archive log files, create backups, and store it in %date% folder on few different drives...

Comment: I tried that already. I want it as \Year\Month\date. md %date% will create folder by today's date

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192476/windows-batch-script-format-date-and-time and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810544/get-date-in-yyyymmdd-format-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: Good. @vrun please accept my answer as right one. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just try to create the folder as a subfolder.

If that fails because the outer folder does not exist, we have the desired behaviour, and all we need to do is ignore the error.