# How to get the date format in windows batch file as 'yyyymmdd'?

Tags: sql-server, windows, date, batch-file, bcp

I am writing a `Windows` Batch file and the `batch file` is supposed to output a file in a specific folder. I want the filename to be written as follows:

```
filename-yyyymmdd.csv
```

where yyyymmdd stands for the current date.

My `batch file` codes stand as follows:

```
cd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn
bcp "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM xxxx.dbo.xxxxx" queryout c:\test\csv\confirmed.csv -t, -c -S xxxx\xxxxx -U xxx -P xxxxxxxxxx
set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%
echo %mydate%
copy c:\test\csv\confirmed.csv c:\test\csvwithdates\confirmed-%mydate%.csv
```

I am getting the following filename as output:  `confirmed-ay18.csv`

Desired output: `confirmed-20180528.csv`

I had a look into the following questions on `StackOverflow` but I am having a hard time implementing the suggested answers:

[Get Date in YYYYMMDD format in windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810544/get-date-in-yyyymmdd-format-in-windows-batch-file)

[Windows batch: formatted date into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945572/windows-batch-formatted-date-into-variable)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why use the old `CMD` (20+ years old) batch syntax instead of Powershell ? Powershell is the *primary* scripting interface for all Microsoft Server products. You can use eg `Invoke-SqlCmd` from the [sqlserver package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps#examples) to query, format and export data.

Comment: The 20 years old `cmd` syntax was never meant to perform complex string formatting. On the other hand, string formatting in Powershell can use the same format strings , methods as .NET making string manipulation a *lot* easier. eg `(get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')` to return `20180528` or `(get-date).ToString('o')` for a full ISO8601 format

Comment: you shouldn't try to get any data from `%date%`, as it's locale dependent and can vary from system to system and even from user to user. Use one of the methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name/18024049#18024049) instead.

Comment: Never tried Powershell. Thanks for that link. I will go through it and it does seem to be well suited for sql queries.

Comment: @Stephan this is a SQL Server question, not a batch question. There are far better ways to do what the OP asks than trying to manipulate strings with the old batch. Hard to beat `(get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: so `set mydate=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%` is SQL? Sorry, I thought it was batch... And `(get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')` transforms to `for /f %%a in ('"powershell (get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"') do set "mydate=%%a"` to get it into a variable usable by OP's script.

Comment: @Stephan in a far more complex, far more verbose and error prone way. Please check the question again. The OP wants to *call bcp* to export 100 rows to a file. It's far easier to do this using Powershell or the `sqlserver` package.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I don't know SQL, I have no Idea, what you're talking about. Shall I undo the "duplicate" so you can add an answer?

Comment: I see no point in arguing about which method to get the date is better especially when it is just for getting the date for the file name.

Answer (score 10):

The dynamic environment variable `DATE` supplies the current local date in region dependent format, i.e. according to the country set in Windows Region and Language options for used account. Wikipedia article [Date format by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) lists the various date formats used in countries all over the world.

So it is necessary to run with the account used on running the batch file in a command prompt window `echo %DATE%` and look on output date string.

Does output date start with an abbreviated weekday or is the date output without weekday? Is first output day and next month with digits or is first output month and next day? Is the month output as number or with name? Is day of month or the month with a value less than 10 output with a leading 0 and so always with two digits or with just one digit?

A very common command line for modifying a region dependent date string in the format `ddd, dd.MM.yyyy` with `.` or `/` or any other delimiter character to `yyyyMMdd` is:

```
set "LocalDate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%"
```

The date string is substituted from right to make string substitution independent on presence of weekday at beginning of date string.

For region dependent date string `ddd, MM/dd/yyyy` the command line to use is:

```
set "LocalDate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%"
```

Which string substitution is necessary can be easily find out by running the commands in a command prompt window with using command **ECHO** instead of **SET**:

```
echo %DATE%
echo %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%
echo %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-10,2%%DATE:~-7,2%
```

See also [What does %date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2% mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147552/)

The advantage of using dynamic environment variable `DATE` is the speed as this string substitution is done by Windows command processor very fast. The disadvantage is the varying date format because of region/country dependency.

A region independent solution is using command **WMIC** as demonstrated below:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDate=%%I"
set "LocalDate=%LocalDate:~0,8%"
```

**WMIC** outputs the date string always in the format **yyyyMMddHHmmss.microsecond±UTC offset in minutes** independent on which country is configured and which date format is set for the country.

The disadvantage of using **WMIC** is the time required for execution as it needs more than a second to output the date string UTF-16 Little Endian encoded processed next by command **FOR**.

See answer on [Why does %date% produce a different result in batch file executed as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670322) for a very detailed explanation on how those two command lines work on execution by Windows command processor `cmd.exe`.

Complete batch file:

```
@echo off
cd /D "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn"
bcp.exe "SELECT TOP 100 * FROM xxxx.dbo.xxxxx" queryout C:\test\csv\confirmed.csv -t, -c -S xxxx\xxxxx -U xxx -P xxxxxxxxxx
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "LocalDate=%%I"
set "LocalDate=%LocalDate:~0,8%"
copy /Y C:\test\csv\confirmed.csv C:\test\csvwithdates\confirmed-%LocalDate%.csv
set "LocalDate="
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

Comment: +1, especially, but not exclusively for `current local date in region dependent format` - a fact so easily ignored by most.