# echo line to >> fun.vbs

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sendkeys

I create a file with a batch script. But I have a problem when I use %.

```
echo WshShell.SendKeys "%" >> fun.vbs
```

But when I check the vbs script I see this

```
WshShell.SendKeys ""
```

How Can I place the '%' in the vbscript ?

Thanks for your reply !

Comment: your first command works for me.

Comment: You can try using `echo "WshShell.SendKeys "%"" >> fun.vbs`

Comment: That is isn't working. But the answer of Akostadinov is working !

Comment: consider a hybrid batch/vbscript file -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try double `%`, i.e. `%%`

Here is the [link](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) to where this is explained. Look at this site, it is an amazing reference for cmd.exe

btw I can't stop myself from recommending you learn linux and bash instead of cmd.exe if you have the choice.

Comment: Thank you very much !! This is working. Thanks again. You made my day. I search very long for the sollusions. Didnt know its so easy.

Comment: @user2355506 What Windows do you have? I have tested it with doubling percentage and in output I had double percentage.

Comment: @user2355506, glad it helped. You can click the "Accept" of the answer if you are happy with it. I know you still can't vote.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - Percents must be doubled when in a batch script. But they should not be doubled when used on the command line.

Comment: @dbenham I missed the part where he said he runs the command from a batch. Then you are right.

Comment: @akostadinov I use Windows 7. It works there. On a standalone pc but also on a domain computer.

Comment: @dbenham. I creating a batch file with some fun in it. But sometimes i create quickly a vbs script and remove it after wscript stoped. To keep the pc clean. 

I use Windows 7 Pro and Ultimate. It works on all.