# How to automate Internet Explorer by a batch file?

Tags: internet-explorer, batch-file

I am new for batch file writing.

When I wrote a file,

```
start /d"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" iexplore.exe gmail.com
```

browser opens with the gmail page.

How to send username and password from the batch file so that I go to my mail page on one click ?

Comment: not possible with simple batch.You can try with vbscript/jscript/powershell or with external tools like cURL.Check thid for example http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech.php#Internet

Comment: use a programming language like Perl, Python with libraries to read your mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

save this as `.bat`

```
:sub echo(str) :end sub
echo off
'>nul 2>&1|| @copy /Y %windir%\System32\doskey.exe %windir%\System32\'.exe >nul
'>nul 2>&1|| @copy /Y %windir%\System32\doskey.exe '.exe >nul

'& set "murl=https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail"
'& set "pass=somepass"
'& set "user=someuser"
'& cscript /nologo /E:vbscript %~f0 %murl% %user% %pass% 


'& rem del /q "%windir%\System32\'.exe"
'& exit /b


URLToM=WScript.Arguments.Item(0)

Dim  objIE, strAllText
Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )
objIE.Visible = True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'extract document data function

Sub URLProcess(strURL,objIE,User,Pass,objFSO)

    Dim blnTimedOut, i      
    objIE.Navigate2 strURL

    Do While objIE.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 150
        i = i + 1
        ' Time out after 10 seconds
        If i > 100 Then
            blnTimedOut = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop


objIE.Document.all.Email.Value = User
objIE.Document.all.Passwd.Value  = Pass 
objIE.Document.all.signIn.Click() 

end SUB

Call URLProcess(URLToM,objIE,WScript.Arguments.Item(1),WScript.Arguments.Item(2),objFSO)

'objIE.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

and set a correct  password and user at the beginning.[This is an batch/vbscript hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16622325/388389)