# Batch file to launch programs in Win 7 (regular+admin)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, batch-file

Each day when I get to work I have to start a bunch of programs and this can take ten minutes or more to do so I was wanting to automate the process by writing a batch file to open everything for me.

So far I've got IE & Outlook to launch fine using:

```
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" iexplore.exe
start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE" Outlook
```

However I also need to launch an instance of IE in my admin account & trying:

```
start runas /profile /savecred /user:!ofnn "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

iexplore.exe which I found on another question here does nothing. IE doesn't open & I don't see the UAC prompt that I'm expecting so I can enter my password.

Also regarding IE & bearing in mind I can't change the default home page settings due to corporate restrictions is it possible to specify a list of urls in the batch script for IE to open? I would have 7 in the regular IE & another 6 in the admin instance.

Comment: [These](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21022579/2982225) [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/188850/2982225) might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using a batch file to just start applications on Windows start?

It is much easier to put shortcuts (*.lnk) files into the **Startup** folder of the Windows start menu. Every user account has its own **Startup** folder in its start menu folder.

Create a shortcut to outlook.exe in your **Startup** folder and Windows will start Outlook after you logged in, except you hold SHIFT after login which Windows recognizes and interprets as ignoring the shortcuts in the **Startup** folder.

[IE Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx) documents the command line options of Internet Explorer. See [How to open multiple tabs in IE8 from the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/513979/how-to-open-multiple-tabs-in-ie8-from-the-command-prompt) containing the solution to open multiple URLs tabbed in Internet Explorer using a Visual Basic script. The shortcut in the **Startup** folder is a link to wscript.exe with the script file as parameter.

Comment: We move between machines semi regularly but our personal network drive always stays the same. So having a bat file means I can link to that from the startup folder which will take 5 seconds and everything will work the same on the new machine. Also I have 4 (at least) programs that require admin rights to start. I believe with a bat file I can simple enter the details once and they will all start whereas I'm guessing it would require credentials for each shortcut in windows startup folder