# passing a parameter from a vbscript to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

I have a batch file calling a vbscript. The VBscript return the current date time stamp.
Can anyone please tell me how I can pass the datestamp value to the batch script . I am 
currently using `Wscript.Echo` which I dont want to use :

batch file :

```
wscript "C:\Script.vbs"  "C:\Log.txt"
```

vb script :

```
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments

Dim objFSO, objFile, LogFile

LogFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(LogFile)
Wscript.Echo objFile.DateLastModified

End If
```

Can any one tell me what I can do in the above script to pass the `datelastmodified` to 
the batch file ? I do not want to use `Wscript.Echo` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('cscript /nologo "C:\Script.vbs"  "C:\Log.txt"') do @set "result=%%#"
```

Now you can use `%result%` variable.

Wscript will pop-up the result.From command line/bat is better to use cscript.

You can also embed the [vbscript code into the batch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/388389)

Comment: I am sorry . I am still new .. So the above code you have.. does that replace the batch file code ?

Comment: @PowerCoder .Yes - this is the way you call the vbscript.

Comment: Thanks ! and should I leave the Wscript.echo statement in the VBScript as it is ??

Comment: @PowerCoder  - you don't need to change the vbscript file.Only the way you call it. Just `cscript.exe` outputs to the console and `wscript.exe` uses pop-ups.