# How to merge batch code with vbscript code

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript, merge

Sometimes in my batch scripts I usually merge batch code with JavaScript code (.js file), like this:

```
@if(@X)==(@Y) @end /*          ← Hybrid line. Starts a Javascript comment block.
::Batch code
@echo off
set code=65
cscript //nologo /E:JScript "%~f0" %code%      ← Calls itself using cscript.exe.
pause>nul
exit/b
*/                        ← Ends the comment block, now we can write JavaSCript.
//JavaScript code
WScript.echo(String.fromCharCode(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)));
```

Its output is `A` (65 ASCII).

Ok, JavaSCript works fine. My question is: How do I do that with `VBScript`? I am not an expert in VBScript, but I know there's not any way to make comment blocks in my code, hence I can't use the same technique as I used with JavaScript.

Supposing I have a code that does the same thing (converts ASCII code passed on first parameter to a char), but now in VBScript:

```
WScript.echo chr(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))
```

How can I merge this VBScript code with my batch code as I did with JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What i have used. To be saved as `.cmd` file

```
<?xml : version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> ^<!-- This is the cmd zone ---------

@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "code=65"
    cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:mainJob %code%
    exit /b

------------------------------------------------ This is the vbs zone ------->
<package>
  <job id="mainJob">
    <script language="VBScript"><![CDATA[

        If WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Count > 0 Then 
            WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Chr(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))
        End If

    ]]></script>
  </job>
</package>
```

Two tricks are used in this case. The first one is hide the cmd part inside a xml comment inside a wsf file that will execute the vbscript part. The second trick is the call to cscript with the cmd file as the script to execute using `"%~f0?.wsf"`, that will make `cscript` handle the file as a `.wsf` file while the real extension is `.cmd`

But you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/2861476) for a exhaustive analysis of the problem.