# How to Close InfoBox.Popup on Timer Expiration?

Tags: vba

I cobbled this test procedure together in Outlook 2013 from other posts.

It should display a popup box, and then close after 3 seconds.

It never closes.

```vb
Sub MessageBoxTimer()
    Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    AckTime = 3
    Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Click OK (this window closes automatically after 3 seconds).", _
    AckTime, "This is your Message Box", 0)
    Case 1, -1
        Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is not related to Outlook at all.

Comment: Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I believe it is a common for all Office applications, not only Outlook. At least I don't see any Outlook's object involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WScript.Shell .Popup seems to be hit or miss in Office VBA.

If you are looking for a MsgBox that works in Office VBA and supports a timeout, I posted another method that uses a **Windows API** call.  It supports timeout, carriage returns, and return values.  [You can find the code at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512186/1898524). I did not think it was proper etiquette to post it again here.

Note that the **mshta** method mentioned by @Orphid does not support carriage returns and always shows the message on the primary monitor.

Answer (score 6):

Some research suggests that this may be a bug in some MS Office applications. I'm basing this on the fact that [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156593.aspx) and [this](http://ss64.com/vb/popup.html) don't seem to say anything which suggests you're using the command in the wrong way, and [this](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/143673-visual-basic-applications-msgbox-timer.html) shows that other users have managed to get precisely this code to work.

I tested this on my Windows PC running Excel with Office 365 and have had the same issue as you - the message box is displayed, but not closed. I found a suggested workaround [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/251143a6-e4ea-4359-b821-34877ddf91fb/wshpopup-timeout-bug), and the discussion on that page may be of some interest to you (particularly one user's description of trying to submit a bug report to Microsoft about VBA). The solution, proposed by a user called ウィンドウズスクリプトプログラマ, is to make a call through to the native user32.dll by declaring an external function - [this](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp) page has some examples of how to call C dlls with VBA.The MessageBoxTimeout function is said to be undocumented by Microsoft, but you can find out a lot about it [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MessageBoxTimeout.html).

The other option, which worked for me, is run a vbscript call to Shell.Popup with mshta.exe:

```
Function Test()

    Dim Shell
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Shell.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(""Test"",3,""Message""))"

End Function
```

To get this to work with more complex messages, you may need to escape some characters. There is another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134997/can-i-run-vbscript-commands-directly-from-the-command-line-i-e-without-a-vbs-f) which shows other uses for mshta's ability to execute vbscript in a shell/ console.

Finally, as was suggested by one user, you could simply create a custom user form with a doevents loop that counts down and then closes itself.

Comment: surprisingly this code removes `vbNewLine` or `vbCrLf` and `\n` is not working so practically I am curious to know how I can insert a line break in the message?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm that result: the 'Timeout' on the WsShell.Popup function is no longer working in Office.

It took me a while to notice, because popup dialogs with a 'cancel' button seem to be affected less. So this might be a usable workaround for you:

```
Dim msg AS String
Dim Title as String

msg ="Click 'Ok' or 'Cancel' (this window closes automatically after 3 seconds)."
Title = Application.name & ": Message Box test"

Select Case InfoBox.Popup(msg, AckTime, Title, vbQuestion + vbOkCancel)
```

If that doesn't work, you're going to need [a much longer explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274103/whats-the-best-way-to-display-a-message-box-with-a-timeout-value-from-vba/35139233#35139233): reimplementing the 'Timeout' using an API Timer Callback. As the author of that answer, I should warn you that this is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut *after* attempting the task with a prolonged naval bombardment.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code to control VBA msg box auto closer after 40 sec. You can try also it. It will work for you.

```
 'The first part
#If Win64 Then '64?
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MsgBoxTimeout _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
            ByVal wlange As Long, _
            ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
    As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
            ByVal wlange As Long, _
            ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
    As Long
#End If
'The second part
Sub btnMsgbox(message As String)
    Call MsgBoxTimeout(0, message, "", vbInformation, 0, 40000)
End Sub
```