# Close/Save outlook messages

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, outlook, autosave

Is it possible to close outlook and save any draft messages using batch?  I know it can be done using VBS (in fact I've already done it) but my boss has requested I do it in batch script.

I so far have:

```
@echo off
taskkill /IM outlook.exe
```

which obviously just kills the entire process but it doesn't save any drafts and will just wait with the prompt if there is one.

Comment: Batch can't interact with GUIs and Outlook doesn't have a command line option to save drafts. Write your code in VBS and stick it in a batch wrapper.

Comment: could you make this an answer please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, batch cannot interact with GUIs, and Outlook [has no command line option to save drafts](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6).

However, since you have already written a working script in VBS, I recommend [writing a batch wrapper script for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a) and giving that to your boss.