# How to edit shortcut properties where shortcut name has registered text ®

Tags: powershell, batch-file, special-characters, shortcut

I am trying to edit the properties of the shortcut using batch script. But the short cut name includes a character ® hence when i run the changeproperties.bat file it fails to read the file name correctly.  I am able to do the same task via poweshell.
My powershell script has belwo line and it works

```
    $shortCut = ("$desktop\testapp®.lnk")
    $shell = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
    $shortcut = $shell.CreateShortcut($shortCut)  ## Open the lnk
    $shortcut.TargetPath = "C:\Users\Public\newtarget.bat"
    $shortCut.Save()
```

The machine where i will run this will not have permission to  run powershell. Hence trying to write similar bat file.

```
    echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
    echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\testapp®©.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\Public\newtarget.bat" >> %SCRIPT%
    echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
```

But this is not working. When i run it creates shortcut with extra added special character like this testappÂ©.

How to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first save your file with `Notepad++` with `ANSI`
Then execute this code and it will works for you.

```
@echo off
(   
    echo Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\testapp®.lnk"
    echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile^)
    echo oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\Public\newtarget.bat"
    echo oLink.Save
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
cscript /nologo %tmp%\%~n0.vbs
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a [Batch + VBScript hybrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074483/1683264) solution would let you circumvent any Batch codepage issues, as well as removing the need to echo your VBScript code to a secondary script.

```js
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf"
exit /b

----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
    Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    userProfile = oWS.Environment("Process").Item("USERPROFILE")
    sLinkFile = userProfile & "\Desktop\testapp®.lnk"
    Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
    oLink.TargetPath = "C:\Users\Public\newtarget.bat"
    oLink.Save
</script></job>
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. First one had the same issue. Hackoo's script did the job for me.

Comment: @Gopichandan Yeah, I tested it and found the same issue, so I just removed it.  Glad Hackoo's solution worked for you though!