# How to have binary stored in batch file and turned into a file?

Tags: batch-file

So when i saw the flappy bird in batch i looked through the code and saw this:

```
 ) Do >> "FLAPPY.zi_" (Echo.For b=1 To len^(%%b^) Step 2
   Echo WScript.StdOut.Write Chr^(Clng^("&H"^&Mid^(%%b,b,2^)^)^) : Next)
   Cscript /b /e:vbs "FLAPPY.zi_" > "FLAPPY.zip"
   Del "FLAPPY.zi_" >nul 2>&1
   UNZIP FLAPPY.ZIP
   Del/q UNZIP.EXE
   del/q FLAPPY.ZIP
   echo.
   echo Installed succesfully, press a key to play
   pause>nul
   goto:eof
```

and above

```
) Do >> "FLAPPY.zi_" (Echo.For b=1 To len^(%%b^) Step 2
```

there is binary code. The full code is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bl2JRE8ssYzvGMhacZ8hf-AyBQeageseC0o-iTWy_Hg/edit?usp=sharing

So is there a way that I can convert a file to binary?

And then convert it back to a file?

Comment: my Antivirus program doesn't like one of the generated `exe` files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure batch cannot write null bytes (0x00). You can use [various hybrid techniques](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5543) to combine batch with more powerful languages like [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/1012053), JScript, PowerShell that can relatively easily read/write binary data.

But probably the simplest thing to use is CERTUTIL. It has various verb options that can convert binary data to hexadecimal or base64, and vice versa.

The following commands provide help for the relevant verb options:

```
:: Hexadecimal conversion
certutil -encodehex -?
certutil -decodehex -?

:: Base 64 conversion
certutil -encode -?
certutil -decode -?
```

The encode verbs add extra content to the output that do not interfere with the decode verbs. You can safely remove the extra info and reformat the encode files, and the decode verbs will still work.

Somewhere on DosTips.com is a good thread that demonstrates how to use CERTUTIL to read/write binary files, but I haven't been able to locate it.

Here is a trivial .bat example that has all 256 byte values embedded within the script, and it extracts the hex data to a temp file, uses CERTUTIL to decode the hex to a 256 byte binary file, and then uses CERTUTIL again to encode the binary file into hex.

```
@echo off
::: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
::: 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F
::: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F
::: 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F
::: 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F
::: 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F
::: 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F
::: 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F
::: 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 8A 8B 8C 8D 8E 8F
::: 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 9A 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F
::: A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 AA AB AC AD AE AF
::: B0 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8 B9 BA BB BC BD BE BF
::: C0 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 CA CB CC CD CE CF
::: D0 D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 DA DB DC DD DE DF
::: E0 E1 E2 E3 E4 E5 E6 E7 E8 E9 EA EB EC ED EE EF
::: F0 F1 F2 F3 F4 F5 F6 F7 F8 F9 FA FB FC FD FE FF
>hex.temp (
  for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr "^:::" "%~f0"') do echo %%A
)

certutil -f -decodeHex hex.temp out.bin >nul

certutil -f -encodeHex out.bin out.hex >nul

del hex.temp
```