# Bat File do delayed keypress

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch script which opens Spotify and starts the playlist by sending the keypress spacebar

What I got is the following

```
start chrome.exe "https://play.spotify.com/chart/4rcbQSKQHID0UdZzODxg2Y"
sleep 8
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{SPACE}");
```

which opens the browser with the mentioned website. Sadly nothing happens after that. Anybody got an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: sleep is not a valid command

Comment: You aren't saying where to send the keys. `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """c:\program files\chrome\chrome.exe"" ""https://play.spotify.com/chart/4rcbQSKQHID0UdZzODxg2Y""":WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Spotify - Chrome":WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys " "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`SendKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/8c6yea83(v=vs.84)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) [documentation](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx):

> To send a space, send the string " ".

So you must send `" "` instead of `{SPACE}`

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys(" ");
```

More importantly, it's a [Windows Script Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) command so you can't run it directly in a batch file. You must store it in a separate vbs file and then run that file or use a [hybrid batch-vbs file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/995714). Otherwise you'll get an error like this

> `'WScript.CreateObject'` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: I updated my post and used the information which were provided by you

Comment: Please don't update the code in the question with the correct one. That'll make available answers incorrect and is not allowed on SO