# Batch script doesn't run, although its code runs in CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I was looking for an easy way to get the system volumes info in GB (batch) so I got this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-3" %a in ('WMIC LOGICALDISK GET FreeSpace^,Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name"') do @echo wsh.echo "%b" ^& " free=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%a^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GiB"^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%c^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GiB" > %temp%\tmp.vbs & @if not "%c"=="" @echo(& @cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs >> c:\test\test2.txt | type C:\test\test2.txt
```

It works fine if I just copy and paste it to the CMD but if I run it from a .bat file it just don't do anything.

What could I be doing wrong?

PD: I can't use PowerShell, I need it in batch.

Comment: That's not batch, it's a fruitless attempt to write vbs in a single line pass values to it wrap that in a for /f processing wmic output. wmic can return proper values but batch is limited to signed 32bit calculations what's +/-2GB. Why can't you use PowerShell? There were 2 similar questions the last two days. Use the search box above.

Comment: Batch files require the `%`-signs for all `for` meta-variables to be doubled, like `%%a`, for instance... By the way, I don't understand the `| type C:\test\test2.txt`; shouldn't it actually read `& type C:\test\test2.txt`?

Comment: I can't use powershell because I need to run this on different machines and some of them have powershell disabled.
@aschipfl I'll add the missing %, If I use "&" symbol it actually displays the output two times but if I use " | " it displays the output 1 time as it should be. Not sure if "|   " is not a valid symbol, I'm a linux guy and this is my first time dealing with windows scripts.

Comment: Related: [Get size of a directory in 'MB' using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36301198). By the way, you should not query the `Name` but the `DeviceID` value; see also [this SU post](https://superuser.com/q/1074840)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues in your code:

- in batch files, `for` meta-variables must be preceded by *two* `%`-signs in contrast to one in command prompt (`cmd`), hence change `%a`, etc., to `%%a`, etc.; otherwise, a syntax error arises;
- you could avoid filtering out the headline of the output of `wmic` by `findstr /V` when using the `skip=1` option of `for /F`;
- instead of the property `Name` I recommend to use `DeviceID`, according to this Super User thread: [What is the difference between properties `Name`, `Caption` and `DeviceID` (when executing `wmic LogicalDisk`)?](https://superuser.com/q/1074840);
- not sure what drives you want to query, but perhaps you want local disks only; if so, add the clause `where "DriveType=3"`; refer to this Microsoft article: [Win32_LogicalDisk class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-logicaldisk);
- creation of the temporary VBScript script should happen inside of the `if` condition where it is called as well in order to avoid pointless file write activities;
- you are appending to the text file in every loop iteration, but you never initialise an empty file at the beginning; perhaps this is the intentional behaviour, but I do not think so; anyway, you could do the redirection once for the whole `for /F` loop, either (over-)writing (`>`) or appending (`>>`), as you prefer;
- the pipe into the `type` command is useless, because `type` does not accept any incoming data anyway; I guess the `|` symbol should have been replaced by `&`; nevertheless, the `type` command does not make sense in the loop, I think it should be executed after the loop instead to display the complete collected data once;
- the `echo(` could be removed as it just writes a blank line to the console;
- at the end the temporary VBScript file should be cleaned up;

Correcting all these things lead to a batch script like this (I do not write it all in a single line for readability):

```cmd
> "C:\test\test2.txt" (
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
        wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size
    ') do @(
        if not "%%c"=="" (
            > "%TEMP%\tmp.vbs" echo WScript.Echo "%%a" ^& " free=" ^& FormatNumber^(CDbl^(%%b^) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2^) ^& " GiB" ^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(CDbl^(%%c^) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2^) ^& " GiB"
            CScript //NoLogo "%TEMP%\tmp.vbs"
        )
    )
)
type "C:\test\test2.txt"
del "%TEMP%\tmp.vbs"
```

---

The whole approach could be improved though:

- the temporary VBScript script could be written once rather than per each `for /F` loop iteration; for this to work you need to pass the variable values as command line arguments; consult this thread to learn how it works: [Using command line arguments in VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2469754);
- using `echo` to write the temporary VBScript file requires lots of escaping, like `^&`, for example; to avoid this, we could place the VBScript code in a block that is prefixed by `::::`, which is seen as an invalid jump label by the batch file interpreter, and they could even be skipped by placing an `exit /B` just before them; this block can easily be extracted by `findstr`, and the colons can be removed by `for /F`;

So this is what I mean:

```cmd
> "%TEMP%\tmp.vbs" (for /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%z in ('findstr /B "::::" "%~f0"') do @echo/%%z)
> "C:\test\test2.txt" (
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
        wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size
    ') do @(
        if not "%%c"=="" CScript //NoLogo "%TEMP%\tmp.vbs" "%%a" "%%b" "%%c"
    )
)
type "C:\test\test2.txt"
del "%TEMP%\tmp.vbs"
exit /B

::::If WScript.Arguments.Count < 3 Then WScript.Quit 1
::::WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & _
::::    " free=" & FormatNumber(CDbl(WScript.Arguments.Item(1)) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GiB" & _
::::    " size=" & FormatNumber(CDbl(WScript.Arguments.Item(2)) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GiB"
```

---

You could even avoid a temporary file holding the VBScript code when applying the technique demonstrated in this thread: [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476)
(Refer also to these Microsoft articles: [Using Windows Script Files (.wsf)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15x4407c.aspx), and [How Come You Guys Don’t Use .WSF Files?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gstemp/2004/02/24/how-come-you-guys-dont-use-wsf-files/).)

```cmd
<!-- :Batch script section
> "C:\test\test2.txt" (
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
        wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size
    ') do @(
        if not "%%c"=="" CScript //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" "%%a" "%%b" "%%c"
    )
)
type "C:\test\test2.txt"
exit /B

---- WSF script section -->
<job><script language="VBScript">
    If WScript.Arguments.Count < 3 Then WScript.Quit 1
    WScript.Echo WScript.Arguments.Item(0) & _
        " free=" & FormatNumber(CDbl(WScript.Arguments.Item(1)) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GiB" & _
        " size=" & FormatNumber(CDbl(WScript.Arguments.Item(2)) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GiB"
</script></job>
```

---

And here is yet another approach that does not use a temporary VBScript file, applying the method illustrated in this thread: [HTA & Batch Hybrid, passing variables from BATCH section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43105028). The disadvantage of this is brief flickers of HTA windows appearing and disappearing.
(Refer also to this Microsoft article: [HTML Applications (HTAs)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/noahc/2007/03/26/html-applications-htas/).)

```cmd
<!-- ::Batch script section ----
> "C:\test\test2.txt" (
    for /F "skip=1 tokens=1-3" %%a in ('
        wmic LogicalDisk where "DriveType=3" get DeviceID^,FreeSpace^,Size
    ') do @(
        if not "%%c"=="" set "DeviceID=%%a" & set "FreeSpace=%%b" & set "Size=%%c" & MSHTA "%~f0"
    )
)
type "C:\test\test2.txt"
exit /B

---- ::HTA script section -->
<script language="VBScript">
    Set Env = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process")
    Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)
    If Not Env("DeviceID") = "" Then
        StdOut.WriteLine(Env("DeviceID") & _
            " free=" & FormatNumber(CDbl(Env("FreeSpace")) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GiB" & _
            " size=" & FormatNumber(CDbl(Env("Size")) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2) & " GiB")
    End If
    Set StdOut = Nothing
    Set Env = Nothing
    Close()
</script>
```