# How to write VBScript from batch?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have a problem with adding `VBScript` to a `Batch` file.
I tried this:

```batch
@echo off
echo MsgBox("Hello")
echo Do
echo MsgBox("Hello")
echo Loop >>msg2.vbs
start msg2.vbs
```

But it gave me an error that I used `Loop` without `Do`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no need to use a temporary vbs file. You can embed and execute vbs code directly within your batch script. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/1012053

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)

Comment: @dbenham Just because you *can* insert sharp and pointy objects into your body doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: but @dbenham i `want`.

Comment: I never meant to imply that there is something wrong with using a temporary file. I was simply pointing out there is another option.

Comment: @dbenham I was half-joking. However, at the end of the day I do consider these Frankenscripts problematic, because they're harder to understand, troubleshoot, and maintain than separate scripts. As a sysadmin I believe we should refrain from making things more complicated than they need to be for the person coming after us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Batch script actually only append loop to msg2.vbs file on each run..

You should append all 'vbs' lines from your batch file like this:

```
@echo off
echo msgBox("Hello") > msg2.vbs    :: > creates file if not exists with: msgBox("Hello")
echo do >> msg2.vbs                :: >> appends line with: do
echo msgBox("Hello") >> msg2.vbs   :: >> appends line with: msgBox("Hello") 
echo loop >> msg2.vbs              :: >> appends line with: loop
start msg2.vbs
```

Answer (score 1):

Your batch file doesn't magically know which lines you want in the VBScript. Either redirect each `echo` output (as [agriffaut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441520/1630171) suggested), or run the `echo` statements in a command block and redirect the entire output of that block (so you don't have to append repeatedly):

```batch
(
  echo MsgBox("Hello"^)
  echo Do
  echo MsgBox("Hello"^)
  echo Loop
)>msg2.vbs
```

Note that for the latter you need to escape closing parentheses inside the block. In this particular case you could just remove them entirely, though:

```batch
(
  echo MsgBox "Hello"
  echo Do
  echo MsgBox "Hello"
  echo Loop
)>msg2.vbs
```

Another option would be using a single `echo` statement and escaping the line breaks:

```batch
>msg2.vbs echo MsgBox "Hello"^

Do^

MsgBox "Hello"^

Loop
```

Note that the blank lines are required here.