# Run VBScript code in a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, embed

Say I have a batch script and I would like to use VBScript to perform a certain task. It is a one liner in VBScript, and I would prefer to only have one file (which is the batch script) without any temporary files. Is this possible?

I know how to create a VBScript file from a batch script, run it and then delete it, but I don't want to do that because that involves creating an extra file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a?noredirect=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways - you can check for more [***`here`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a?noredirect=1). The best way according to me (save whole code bellow as a .bat):

```
<!-- :
@echo off
echo "Batch code here"
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %*
exit /b
-->
<job><script language="VBScript">
  WScript.Echo "VBScript output called by batch"
  'Uncoment if you want to test the command line arguments
  'WScript.Echo (WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
</script></job>
```

You can also use mshta (mind that this the browser based vbscript and you have no access to the WScript object):

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Define simple batch "macros" to implement VBS within batch
set "vbsBegin=mshta vbscript:Execute("createobject(""scripting.filesystemobject"")"
set "vbsBegin=%vbsBegin%.GetStandardStream(1).write("
set ^"vbsEnd=):close"^)"

:: float numbers math
%vbsBegin% 2.5+3.1 %vbsEnd% |more

for /f %%a in ('%vbsBegin% 2.5+3.1 %vbsEnd%') do set result=%%a
echo %result%
```

Comment: Am I able to replace the WScript.Echo line with my own code? I assume I would. I did that and added that into my own script and it is saying it expected a valid name. I doubt the issue is with the code I added but with the way the code is being called.

Comment: @ChristianSirolli - yes you can . Is the error comes from the vbscript code? May be it expects some command line arguments?

Comment: I used the msgbox command like I would in a normal VBScript, which I know works in a normal VBScript. The error appears in the command line console, like a normal command line error does, and I believe the error is thrown when it runs the cscript line.

Comment: @ChristianSirolli - is this line so secret? Have you tried it in a `.vbs` file to see if the problem is not in the vbscript itself?

Comment: As I said, the line works fine in a VBS file. Now I just noticed an edit you make to the code block, where you added a `%*`. I don't think I saw that earlier when I tested it.

Comment: Note: the line I am using is this: `msgbox "Thanks for using this script.", vbInformation+VbMsgBoxSETForeground, "EXIT"`. It works in a VBScript file.

Comment: Here is the error I am getting: `<script path and name>.bat?.wsf(3, 23) Windows Script Host: Expecting a valid name` I replaced the script name and path with `<script path and name>` for privacy reasons. I updated my code with what you changed but am still getting the same error.

Comment: here is the code I am using that it is throwing an error for:

 `@ECHO OFF
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %*
@EXIT /B

<job><script language="VBScript">
  msgbox "Thanks for using this script.", vbInformation+VbMsgBoxSETForeground, "EXIT"
</script></job>`

Comment: Issue was resolved by adding the <!-- and --> in the script

Comment: Now, from experimenting, it seems that `%~f0` from CD. Is there a better way that gets the true file path? This broke it at one point until I set the original directory at the beginning of the script as a variable, which became the current directory when the script exited and ran the vbscript.

Comment: @ChristianSirolli - sorry haven't check the SO for a while.  `%~f0` is the path to batch file. with vbscript you can use `Wscript.ScriptFullName` . If you are running it as admin it will start in `system32` . You can try with setting `cd /d "%~dp0"` at the begining of your script to be sure that directory will be where the script is.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use this

```
<!-- : Begin batch script
@echo off
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" %1
exit /b

----- Begin wsf script --->
<job><script language="VBScript">
:: Remove this line and Write the Vbscript code here or it will not work
</script></job>
```