# Batch+VBS error End of expected statement

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, syntax-error

I have made a batch file that should create vbscript that creates a shortcut of a certain file depicted by the choice command. The only problem is I keep getting a expected end of statement error. I'm assuming it's a Syntax error.
(sorry I don't explain it well as I am new to Vbs) here is the code

```
@echo off
Title Dragonball Z
cls
echo Please Type The Number Corosponding To Your Chosen Title
more "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\Titles.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345 /N /M ":"
if errorlevel 5 goto tlog2
if errorlevel 4 goto tlog
if errorlevel 3 goto t
if errorlevel 2 goto ssw
if errorlevel 1 goto bf

:bf
set DIR=""%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\BUU'S FURY\Dragonball Z Buu's Fury.GBA""
set game="Buus Fury"
goto END

:ssw
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\SUPERSONIC WARRIORS\DragonBall Z Supersonic Warriors.gba"
set game="Supersonic Warriors"
goto END

:t
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\Taiketsu\Dragonball Z Taiketsu.GBA"
set game="Taiketsu"
goto END

:tlog
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\THE LEGACY OF GOKU\Dragonball Z the Legacy of Goku.GBA"
set game="The Legacy of Goku"
goto END

:tlog2
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\THE LEGACY OF GOKU 2\Dragonball Z the Legacy of Goku 2.GBA"
set game="The Legacy of Goku 2"
goto END

:END
set SCRIPT="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%game%.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = %DIR% >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
rem Here I keep getting a Expected End Of statement error
pause
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: It's the `del %SCRIPT%`. Don't use `%RANDOM%`.

Comment: Would this work?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2ZguPAJm

Comment: Bad practice to assign quotes to your variables. Just quote the variable when you need to use it.

Comment: this is a bad pattern to use vbscript like that from batch file. Better check this-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a

Answer (score 0):

Powershell has great uses, Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
Title Dragonball Z
cls
echo Please Type The Number Corosponding To Your Chosen Title
more "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\Titles.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345 /N /M ":"
if errorlevel 5 goto tlog2
if errorlevel 4 goto tlog
if errorlevel 3 goto t
if errorlevel 2 goto ssw
if errorlevel 1 goto bf

:bf
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\BUU'S FURY\Dragonball Z Buu's Fury.GBA"
set game="Buus Fury"
goto END

:ssw
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\SUPERSONIC WARRIORS\DragonBall Z Supersonic Warriors.gba"
set game="Supersonic Warriors"
goto END

:t
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\Taiketsu\Dragonball Z Taiketsu.GBA"
set game="Taiketsu"
goto END

:tlog
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\THE LEGACY OF GOKU\Dragonball Z the Legacy of Goku.GBA"
set game="The Legacy of Goku"
goto END

:tlog2
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\THE LEGACY OF GOKU 2\Dragonball Z the Legacy of Goku 2.GBA"
set game="The Legacy of Goku 2"
goto END

:END
powershell "$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('"%~dp0%game%.LNK"');$s.TargetPath='"%DIR%"';$s.Save()"

pause
goto :EOF
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work I got this-At line:1 char:177
+ ... etPath='"C:\Users\Salina\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\BUU'S FURY\Dr ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token 'S' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: @ImaGonnaDie Yeah just change `$s.TargetPath='"%DIR%"'` to `$s.TargetPath='%DIR%'` As your for statements already quote the path.

Comment: Also just noticed `set DIR=""%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\BUU'S FURY\Dragonball Z Buu's Fury.GBA""` is double quoted. Try not quoting and doing `set "DIR=%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\BUU'S FURY\Dragonball Z Buu's Fury.GBA"` instead

Comment: thanks guys for all your help but I have finished the project already and I have broken each Platform/series into individual batch files but the master/controller bat file code is here https://pastebin.com/KQdKNv7R

Answer (score 0):

try calling the vbscript like this:

```
@echo off
Title Dragonball Z
cls
echo Please Type The Number Corosponding To Your Chosen Title
more "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\Titles.txt"
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 12345 /N /M ":"
if errorlevel 5 goto tlog2
if errorlevel 4 goto tlog
if errorlevel 3 goto t
if errorlevel 2 goto ssw
if errorlevel 1 goto bf

:bf
set DIR=""%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\BUU'S FURY\Dragonball Z Buu's Fury.GBA""
set game="Buus Fury"
goto END

:ssw
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\SUPERSONIC WARRIORS\DragonBall Z Supersonic Warriors.gba"
set game="Supersonic Warriors"
goto END

:t
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\Taiketsu\Dragonball Z Taiketsu.GBA"
set game="Taiketsu"
goto END

:tlog
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\THE LEGACY OF GOKU\Dragonball Z the Legacy of Goku.GBA"
set game="The Legacy of Goku"
goto END

:tlog2
set DIR="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\ROMS\GB\DRAGONBALL Z\THE LEGACY OF GOKU 2\Dragonball Z the Legacy of Goku 2.GBA"
set game="The Legacy of Goku 2"
goto END

:END
cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" //job:VBS
pause
exit /b %errorlevel%



<package> <job id="VBS"> <script language="VBScript">

  Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
  userProfile = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERPROFILE%" )
  game = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%game%" )
  dir1 = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%dir%" )
  Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  sLinkFile = userProfile & "\Desktop\" & game & ".lnk"
  Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
  oLink.TargetPath = dir1
  oLink.Save

</script> </job> </package>
```