# Using FlashWindowEx in a CMD batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, flashwindowex

I have a CMD batch file which takes a long time to process and I wish to alert the user that some input is required by flashing the CMD window.

[This example works great in powershell](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/26/make-a-window-flash-in-taskbar-using-powershell-and-pinvoke/) but if I try to compile it from within CMD by

```
powershell -c "Add-Type -TypeDefinition @\";"^
 "using System;"^
..... and so on
```

it fails at the very first line.
Similar problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373052/how-i-can-use-add-type-in-powershell-through-command-line-in-order-to-execute-vb) but looks like there was never a solution given.

So, does anyone have ideas as to how I can make this work and get my CMD window to flash?

edit: @mklement0's answer got me in the right direction.  THANK YOU.

Comment: @Compo's comment is now gone, but to recap it, with a tl;dr qualification: `;` after `@\"` shouldn't be there, but even without it your code wouldn't work, because PowerShell's here-strings require a _newline_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter, which you cannot provide  from `cmd.exe`, because line continuation with `^` does _not_ insert newlines. Quoting _each line_ with`"..."` is an option, as long as each such line _has whitespace before the opening `"`_. My answer forgoes this for a simpler representation, but it does require selective `^`-escaping of `cmd.exe` metachars.

Answer (score 3):

Passing multiline PowerShell commands from `cmd.exe` is nontrivial and requires lots of careful escaping.

Here's a minimal example with [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Add-Type): Using C# code, it defines class `[Foo]` with a static `Bar()` method and then calls it from PowerShell:

```bash
powershell -noprofile -c Add-Type -TypeDefinition ' ^
  public class Foo { ^
    public static string Bar() { return \"hi!\"; } ^
  } ^
  '; ^
  [Foo]::Bar()
```

- An overview of the escaping rules is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69439031/45375); a few things worth noting here:

  - **[Here-strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@` and `@'<newline>...<neline>'@`) *cannot be used***, because they have strict whitespace requirements, notably requiring a *newline* both immediately after the opening `@"` / `@'` as well as before the closing `@"` / `@'`, whereas `cmd.exe`'s line-continuation with `^` does *not* result in newlines. Therefore, your approach won't work (even with the extraneous `;` after the opening `@"` removed).
  - Use `'...'` ([verbatim (single-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)), where possible, which simplifies escaping.
    Note that **PowerShell's *regular* string literals, not just here-strings, are also capable of spanning multiple lines**,  which the solution above takes advantage of.
  - When you do need to use `"`, escape them as `\"` - if a `"` occurs *alone* or there is an *uneven number* of them on a given interior line, escape it / the last one as `\^"` (sic).

    - Note that anything outside `\"...\"` is seen as *unquoted* by `cmd.exe`, so that metacharacters such as `&` and `|` require individual `^`-escaping there.
- You should be able to apply these rules to your `FlashWindowEx` P/Invoke declaration.

Comment: Thank you this solved my other question ! Would it be wise to escape all " as \^" and not have to  count them to check if there's an even or odd number of doublequotes ?

Comment: @Shodan, if you use this approach, you'll need to individually `^`-escape all other `cmd.exe` metacharacters that occur between `\^"...\^"` too. E.g., instead of `return \"hi & bye!\"`, you'd have to use `return \^"hi ^& bye!\^"`